# actionscript loop working second time

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a mobile app with a SQLite database to store details on the handset, I want to sync the contents of this table via PHP to a remote mySQL server.

I use the following to write the rows to the remote server.

```
protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var result:SQLResult;
            var numRows:int ;
            conn = new SQLConnection();
            conn.open(file, SQLMode.CREATE);
            selectStmt.sqlConnection = conn; 
            var sql:String =  "SELECT * FROM surveyResponseHeader"; 
            selectStmt.text = sql; 
            selectStmt.execute(); 
            result = selectStmt.getResult(); 
            numRows = result.data.length; 
            trace (result.data.length);
            trace (numRows);
            for (var i:int = 0; i< numRows; i++){

                surveyresponse.surveyID = parseInt(result.data[i]["surveyID"]);
                surveyresponse.surveySite =result.data[i]["surveySite"];
                surveyresponse.surveyReference = result.data[i]["surveyReference"];
                surveyresponse.siteManager =result.data[i]["siteManager"];
                surveyresponse.surveyDate = result.data[i]["surveyDate"];
                surveyresponse.surveyNextVisit = result.data[i]["surveyNextVisit"];
                surveyresponse.surveySignature = result.data[i]["surveySignature"];
                surveyresponse.surveyImage =result.data[i]["surveyImage"];
                surveyresponseheaderService.createSurveyresponseheader(surveyresponse);

            }

        }
```

My question:

On the first run only the last row is posted and it is posted multiple times depending on the number of rows returned by the SQLLite query, on the second run it posts properly, why is this?

I have stared at this now for hours and cannot see where I am going wrong.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to trace out things? e.g. from within loop the result.data[i]["surveyID"].
p.s. I suggest to not have all that code in the click handler - t will create noticable lag. Instead use asynchronous methods. Connect once and use it instead of reconnecting on each click.

Comment: Tracing shows i incrementing properly, on the first click event I get the last result 3 times, on the second click I get resulst 1, 2 and 3 as it should

Comment: give a go with events, I'm 100% sure that will work like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to add events listeners:

```
dbStatement.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, resultHandler);
dbStatement.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
dbStatement.execute();
```

then in handler check results:

```
function resultHandler(event:SQLEvent):void
{
    var result:SQLResult = dbStatement.getResult();
    if (result != null)
    {
        var numRows:int = result.data.length;
        for (var i:int = 0; i < numRows; i++)
        {
            var row:Object = result.data[i];
            trace("id:", row.id, ", name:", row.name, ", ssn:", row.ssn);
        }
    }
}

function errorHandler(event:SQLErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("An error occured while executing the statement.");
}
```

as described in [help for execute() method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLStatement.html#execute%28%29)

Comment: OP is opening the connection synchronously, so the results should be available.

Comment: OK, I have added the listeners and handlers and it traces out correctly, however, on the first write to the remote database I still get 3 identical entries on first execute and then 3 correct entries on second execute, I cannot fathom why it is wrong on first execute and right on the second, I am beginning to suspect the data service may well be the culprit here

Comment: surveyresponse - what is that object and when it is initiated? maybe it is worth to have it local? Also yes, you might put some tracers in the createSurveyresponseheader method.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I simply added a new object to hold the results and voila

Answer (score 0):

You want it sorted but you do not include an ORDER BY statement.
SQL will by default sort on the primary key.

To sort on something other then that key you need to specify it with an ORDER BY expression.
An ORDER BY experssion may be optionally followed by one of the keywords ASC (smaller values are returned first) or DESC (larger values are returned first). If neither ASC or DESC are specified, rows are sorted in ascending (smaller values first) order by default.

Comment: Ordering makes no difference mate, I'm trying to understand why on the first execution it gives me the last record returned 3 times and on the second execution it gives me all 3 records as it should.

Comment: OK, I have added the listeners and handlers and it traces out correctly, however, on the first write to the remote database I still get 3 identical entries on first execute and then 3 correct entries on second execute, I cannot fathom why it is wrong on first execute and right on the second, I am beginning to suspect the data service may well be the culprit here – Gavin Jones 43 mins ago